# SQL summation by group

Tags: sql

I have the following table:-

TableA

[image]

I wish to translate the above into:-

[image]

*Conditions:-*
It is always based on the latest Transaction. For example, U001 was recorded twice – 20140102123458 & 20140103082526. In this case, we pick 20140103082526 being the latest.

I used the following SQL to run:-

```
select
CASE x.Length
when '20' then '20/22'
when '21' then '20/22'
when '22' then '20/22'
when '23' then '23/24'
when '24' then '23/24'
end as Range,
x.Grade, sum(x.Length) Length, sum(x.Qty) Qty
from TableA as x
inner join
(
select Serial, max(Transaction) Transaction
from TableA
group by Serial
) as y on (y.Transaction =x.Transaction)
where
x.Serial in ( ‘U001’,‘U002’,‘U003’,‘U004’,‘U005’)
group by x.Length, x.Grade, x.Qty
```

However, the results that I rcv’d are as follows:-

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you want to include Length and Qty in the group by. Did you mean to `Group By` Range and Grade perhaps?

Comment: Yes, group by Range & Grade.

Comment: a fiddle link would be useful

Comment: I'm pretty new to Stack Exchange, Is it good etiquette for me to post that as an answer?

Comment: if its `sql server` try doing partition by(Range) with help of `CTE` then u'd sum(cte.qty) group by cte.Range ?

Comment: Group by Range or CTE.Range doesn't work. It prompted Column or global variable RANGE not found.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure of how to do CTE.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY CASE x.Length
when '20' then '20/22'
when '21' then '20/22'
when '22' then '20/22'
when '23' then '23/24'
when '24' then '23/24'
end, x.Grade`